# Add paths onto a D3.js map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, svg, social-networking, d3.js

I am new to D3.js. I am trying to visualize a social network on a US 
map. It basically includes 20 towers and connections between them. Now 
I can draw circles at each tower, but the paths (straight lines will be 
fine) cannot be seen for some reason.

I am attaching the code to this 
message. Your kind help will be truly appreciated!

The data for path is in csv format and each row includes the id, 
longitude and latitude of the origin tower and the destination tower.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
#states path { 
    fill: #ccc; 
    stroke: #fff; 
} 

path.arc { 
  pointer-events: none; 
  fill: none; 
  stroke: #fff; 
} 

path.cell { 
  fill: none; 
  pointer-events: all; 
} 

circle { 
  fill: steelblue; 
  fill-opacity: .8; 
  stroke: #fff; 
} 

 </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../d3.v2.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../d3.csv.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../d3.geo.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../d3.geom.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
var w = 1280, 
    h = 800; 
var projection = d3.geo.azimuthal() 
    .mode("equidistant") 
    .origin([-98, 38]) 
    .scale(1400) 
    .translate([640, 360]); 
var path = d3.geo.path() 
    .projection(projection); 
var svg = d3.select("body").insert("svg:svg", "h2") 
    .attr("width", w) 
    .attr("height", h); 
var states = svg.append("svg:g") 
    .attr("id", "states"); 
var circles = svg.append("svg:g") 
    .attr("id", "circles"); 
d3.json("../data/us-states.json", function(collection) { 
  states.selectAll("path") 
      .data(collection.features) 
      .enter().append("svg:path") 
      .attr("d", path); 
}); 

d3.csv("K_cdr.csv", function(callls) { 
var countByTower = {}, 
    locationByTower = {}, 
    positions = []; 
callls.forEach(function(calll) { 
var origin = calll.tower_orig, 
destination = calll.tower_dest; 
countByTower[origin] = (countByTower[origin] || 0) + 1; 
countByTower[destination] = (countByTower[destination] || 0) + 1; 
 }); 
d3.csv("K_Towers.csv", function(towers) { 
    var location = []; 
    towers.map(function(tower) { 
    location = [+tower.lat, +tower.lon]; 
    locationByTower[tower.ID] = location; 
    positions.push(projection(location)); 
    }); 
    circles.selectAll("circle") 
           .data(towers) 
           .enter().append("svg:circle") 
           .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return positions[i][0]; }) 
           .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return positions[i][1]; }) 
           .attr("r", function(d, i) { return 
    Math.sqrt(countByTower[d.ID])/2; }); 
    svg.selectAll("circle.node") 
       .data(towers) 
       .enter().append("svg:text") 
       .attr("class", "node") 
       .attr("x", function(d,i) { return positions[i][0]; }) 
       .attr("y", function(d,i) { return positions[i][1]; }) 
       .text(function(d,i) {return d.ID;}); 
    }); 

svg.selectAll("path") 
   .data(callls) 
   .enter().append("path") 
   .attr("d", function(d,i) { 
    var orig = projection([d.tower_orig_lat[i], 
    d.tower_orig_lon[i]]); 
    var dest = projection([d.tower_dest_lat[i], d.tower_dest_lon[i]]); 
    return ("M"+ orig[0]+" "+orig[1]+" L "+ dest[0] +" "+ dest[1] + " 
    z;"); }); 
}); 

    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could pare this down to the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem, and also included a small sample of the CSV needed to produce it. Best would be to host such a minimal example somewhere, either as a gist/bl.ocks, or on http://jsfiddle.net